# How similiar is one text to another

Tags: microsoft-excel

What would be a solution to know how many words are the same comparing the text in one cell to another?

For example, in the third column I get the number of the same words in the columns text-1 and text-2.

| text-1 | text-2 | number of same words text-1 vs text-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| my name is Jaime | my name is Rosa | 3 |
| I have a big family | I have a big family too | 5 |
| My dog is getting sick | I have 2 apples in the fridge | 0 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using REDUCE and TEXTSPLIT we can create two arrays of the words.

Then with REDUCE we can loop through one array and add 1 each time that word is found in the second array using MATCH.

```
=REDUCE(0,TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),LAMBDA(a,b,a+ISNUMBER(MATCH(b,TEXTSPLIT(B2," "),0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed.